# java maximum value of int

Tags: java, loops, infinite

From java documentation `int has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive)`.

I have a class `Test.java`.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i=2147483647; //max positive value an int can store
        for(;;)
        {
            System.out.println(++i);
        }
    }
}
```

As per my knowledge `++i` should increment the value of `i` by 1 and throw exception, because `2147483648` is not allowed in `int`.

But when I run above program it goes running(because of infinite loop), and instead of incrementing the value to `2147483648`, the value assigned to `i` is `-2147483648`, And values is decremented each time by `1`.

Sample run (after modifying class)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int i=2147483647;
    for(;;)
    {
        System.out.println(++i);
        System.out.println(++i);
        System.out.println(++i);
        System.out.println(++i);
        System.out.println(++i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-2147483648
-2147483647
-2147483646
-2147483645
-2147483644
```

Answers/Hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As per my knowledge ++i should increment the value of i by 1 and throw exception, because 2147483648 is not allowed in int.

Your understanding is incorrect. Integer arithmetic overflows silently in Java.

From [section 15.18.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two operand values.

Answer (score 4):

You've encountered a situation known as integer overflow:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Answer (score 2):

This is known as *integer overflow*. Arithmetic operations on integer values never throw an exception, and this is not a Java-only thing.

The minimum and maximum values only serves you to decide if an `int` is or is not enough for your computation.

Answer (score 2):

I won't give the exact answer, but consider this:

- how is an integer represented in Java(in what kind of binair number representation)?
- what happens if you add 1 to the highest possible binair number?

Answer (score 2):

In java underflow and overflow of numeric values are off(silent). During underflow and overflow event Java keeps continuing incrementing/decrementing for numeric value's  range.

[Section 4.2.2. Integer Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2)

> The integer operators do not indicate overflow or underflow in any
>   way.