# Array form of integer

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to convert the array to integer sum=999999999999 (twelve 9) , when i am limiting the array to less than ten 9s it is giving the result but when i am giving the array of more than ten 9s it is giving an unexpected result , please explain it will be really helpful for me

```
int[] arr={9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9};
int p=arr.length-1;
int m;
int num=0;
for (int i = 0; i <= p; i++) {
    m=(int) Math.pow(10, p-i);
    num += arr[i]*m;           // it is executing like: 900+90+9=999
}
```

Comment: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-integermaxvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

- You don't need to use `Math.pow`.
- for up to 18 digits, you can use a `long` to do the computation.
- I added some extra digits to demonstrate

```
int[] arr={9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,1,1,2,3,4};

long sum = 0;             // or BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
for (int val : arr) {
    sum = sum * 10 + val; // or sum.multiply(BigInteger.TEN).add(BigInteger.valueOf(val));
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

prints

```
99999999999911234
```

Here is the sequence for `1,2,3,4` so you can see what is happening.

```
- sum = 0
- sum = sum(0) * 10 + 1 (sum is now 1)
- sum = sum(1) * 10 + 2 (sum is now 12)
- sum = sum(12)* 10 + 3 (sum is now 123)
- sum = sum(123)*10 + 4 (sum is now 1234)
```

Answer (score 2):

this happens because you're exceeding the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer).

You can use instead of `int` a `long`, to store large values,
and if that is not enough for you, you can use - [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

```
BigInteger num = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
for (int i = 0; i <= p; i++) {
    BigInteger m = BigInteger.valueOf((int) Math.pow(10, p-i));
    BigInteger next =  BigInteger.valueOf(arr[i]).multiply(m));
    num = num.add(BigInteger.valueOf(arr[i]*m));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because an int is coded on 4 byte so technically you can only go from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
Consider using the long type.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    public int powers(int base, int exponent) {
        int temp = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
            temp *= base;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public List<Integer> addToArrayForm(int[] nums, int k) {
        long temp = 0;
        int numb = powers(10, nums.length - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
             temp=((long) nums[i] *numb)+temp;
            numb /= 10;
        }

        List <Integer> f=new ArrayList<>();

         long sum = ((long) (temp + k));

       while (sum > 0 ) {
            f.add(0, (int) (sum % 10));
           sum /= 10;
       }

       return f;
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try using long (or any other type which can represent larger numbers) instead of int.
I suggest this because the int overflows: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Because it overflows integer boundry. The maximum integer value that can be stored in Java is 2147483647. When you try to store a value greater than this, the result will be an unexpected value. To solve this issue, you can use a long data type instead of an int data type

you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066337/java-maximum-value-of-int) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)